# Replacing digit words into digits

Tags: java, string, replace

I am trying to replace all digit words zero-nine into their corresponding digits 0-9 in a string.

I have created the two arrays of digit words and digits and then trying for loop with a replace to change the sentence.

Not sure what i am doing wrong.

I'm referencing my `getNoDigitWordString` method.

```
import java.util.*;
public class StringProcessor {
private String noSpaces;
private String input, noVowels;
private String noDigitWords;
private int numOfWords = 0, uppercaseLetters = 0,
            numOfDigits = 0, digitWords = 0;
private String [] wordDigits = {"zero","one", "two", "three","four",
        "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
private String [] digits = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4",
        "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};


public StringProcessor()
{
    input = "";
}

public StringProcessor(String s)
{
    StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(s);
    numOfWords = str.countTokens();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i)))
            uppercaseLetters++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)))
            numOfDigits++;
    }

    String [] strSplit = s.split(" ");
    for(int i = 0; i < strSplit.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < wordDigits.length; j++)
        {
            if (strSplit[i].equalsIgnoreCase(wordDigits[j]))
                    digitWords++;
        }
    }


    noSpaces = s.replace(" ","");
    noVowels = s.replaceAll("[aeiou]", "-");

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        noDigitWords = s.replace("wordDigits[i]", "digits[i]");
    }
}

public void setString(String s)
{
    input = s;
}

public String getString()
{
    return input;
}

public int wordCount()
{
    return numOfWords;
}

public int uppercaseCount()
{
    return uppercaseLetters;
}

public int digitCount()
{
    return numOfDigits;
}

public int digitWordCount()
{
    return digitWords;
}

public String getNoSpaceString()
{
    return noSpaces;
}

public String getNoVowelString()
{
    return noVowels;
}

public String getNoDigitWordString()
{
    return noDigitWords;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String input;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a line of text: ");
    input = keyboard.nextLine();

    StringProcessor str = new StringProcessor(input);

    System.out.println("words: " + str.wordCount());
    System.out.println("uppercase: " + str.uppercaseCount());
    System.out.println("digits: " + str.digitCount());
    System.out.println("digit words " + str.digitWordCount());
    System.out.println("line with no spaces: " + str.getNoSpaceString());
    System.out.println("line with vowels replaced: " + str.getNoVowelString());
    System.out.println("line with digit words replaced: " + str.getNoDigitWordString());
}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: where exactly is your error?

Comment: my output doesn't change one to 1. it stays as one.

Comment: can you put your output? btw I think it stays in one since you're calling each method once. try with a `for` loop on your `main` method, before `System.out.println("words: " + str.wordCount());`

Comment: I mean, what's your actual output and the expected one

Comment: my input is "this is the one". Output is "this is the one". Expected output should be "this is the 1"

Answer (score 4):

This is what you're looking for:

```
noDigitWords = s;
for(int i = 0; i < strSplit.length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < wordDigits.length; j++)
    {
        if (strSplit[i].equalsIgnoreCase(wordDigits[j])){
            noDigitWords = noDigitWords.replace(strSplit[i], digits[j]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    noDigitWords = s.replace("wordDigits[i]", "digits[i]");
}
```

Comment: i tried this but if i enter in two numbers like one and nine only the nine changes to "9". but when i enter only one number in the sentence they change to the corresponding digit

Comment: @PurpleVermont Just a note: don't use words like "below" on StackOverflow since it likes rearranging the answers.  :)

Comment: this won't work for the same reason ajb explains in his/her reply

Comment: To be clean about it, you should copy s to a new variable and then modify that variable.  You could get away with it in this case because noDigitWords happens to be the last thing computed, but if he changes his mind and wants to add a new variant after it, that new thing won't work because you've munged the original string (s).  Leave s alone and munge noDigitWords from the start.

Comment: @PurpleVermont there then, that's it

Comment: Yes, that will work.  I was going to say that you didn't need to complicate matters by using the split, but the benefit of this method is that it will replace all instances regardless of case.

Comment: that's it, while the input isn't "fivezero" (no spaces), this would work

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the problem @dcharms pointed out, this is not going to work:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    noDigitWords = s.replace(wordDigits[i], digits[i]);
}
```

Here's what happens: First, you search `s` for `"zero"`, and call `s.replace`.  This *returns* a string with the word `"zero"` replaced by `"0"`.  Then that string is assigned to `noDigitWords`.  **But `s` itself does not change**.

Then, next time through the loop, you search in the *original* `s` for the next word.  The work you did in the previous iteration, which was in `noDigitWords`, gets thrown away.

The result will be that the last word you search for, `"nine"`, should get replaced.  But any other replacements you've made will be thrown away.

Comment: I ran an input with "nine" and I see what you described. I'm just confused on how to make all the changes stick.

Comment: Use the same variable.  Start with `noDigitWords = s;` and then `noDigitWords = noDigitWords.replace(...)`.

Comment: Edited because `"" + digits[i]` isn't necessary, just `digits[i]` is good enough.  But if `digits[i]` were an `int[]` array instead of `String[]`, the `"" +` would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `noDigitWords = s.replace("wordDigits[i]", "digits[i]");` with `noDigitWords = s;` outside for loop and 
`noDigitWords = noDigitWords.replaceAll(wordDigits[i], digits[i]);` inside.

Your original was looking for a string `"wordDigits[i]"` instead of the contents of `wordDigits[i]`. Your output had a similar issue.

Comment: Still not changing my sentence. I feel like that should work but its not.

Comment: What is your input sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Each time the following code calls the `replace` method, the string `noDigitWords` is overwritten.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    noDigitWords = s.replace("wordDigits[i]", "digits[i]");
}
```

After the final iteration of the loop, the string "one nine" becomes "one 9" rather than "1 9" as desired.  The solution is to call the `replace` method on the return value of the previous iteration of the loop.  Initialize the string `noDigitWords` to the value of the string `s`.  Each iteration do the replace on `noDigitWords` as shown below.

```
noDigitWords = s;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    noDigitWords = noDigitWords.replace(wordDigits[i], digits[i]);
}
```