# print an English phrase that describes the integer

Tags: java, algorithm

Want to print the English representation for a word (between 0 and 999,999), for example, for 1,234, I want to print as “One Thousand, Two Hundred and Thirty Four". Found the following solution, but not sure the logical meaning of line 23 to line 25. Any insights are appreciated. Thanks.

```
 1 public static String numtostring(int num) {
 2    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 3
 4    // Count number of digits in num.
 5    int len = 1;
 6    while (Math.pow((double)10, (double)len ) < num) {
 7       len++;
 8    }
 9
10    String[] wordarr1 = {“”,”One ”, “Two ”, “Three ”, “Four ”,
11       “Five ”, “Six ”, “Seven ”, “Eight ”,”Nine ”};
12    String[] wordarr11 = {“”, “Eleven ”, “Twelve ”, “Thirteen ”,
13       “Fourteen ”, “Fifteen ”, “Sixteen ”,
14       “Seventeen ”, “Eighteen ”, “Nineteen ”};
15    String[] wordarr10 = {“”,”Ten ”, “Twenty ”, “Thirty ”, “Forty ”,
16    “Fifty ”, “Sixty ”, “Seventy ”, “Eighty ”,
17    “Ninety “};
18    String[] wordarr100 = {“”, “Hundred ”, “Thousand ”};
19    int tmp;
20    if (num == 0) {
21       sb.append(“Zero”);
22    } else {
23       if (len > 3 && len % 2 == 0) {
24          len++;
25       }
26       do {
27          // Number greater than 999
28          if (len > 3) {
29             tmp = (num / (int)Math.pow((double)10,(double)len-2));
30             // If tmp is 2 digit number and not a multiple of 10
31             if (tmp / 10 == 1 && tmp%10 != 0) {
32                sb.append(wordarr11[tmp % 10]) ;
33             } else {
34                sb.append(wordarr10[tmp / 10]);
35                sb.append(wordarr1[tmp % 10]);
36             }
37             if (tmp > 0) {
38                sb.append(wordarr100[len / 2]);
39             }
40             num = num % (int)(Math.pow((double)10,(double)len-2));
41             len = len-2;
42          } else { // Number is less than 1000
43             tmp = num / 100;
44             if (tmp != 0) {
45                sb.append(wordarr1[tmp]);
46                sb.append(wordarr100[len / 2]);
47             }
48             tmp = num % 100 ;
49             if(tmp / 10 == 1 && tmp % 10 != 0) {
50                sb.append(wordarr11[tmp % 10]) ;
51             } else {
52                sb.append(wordarr10[tmp / 10]);
53                sb.append(wordarr1[tmp % 10]);
54             }
55             len = 0;
56          }
57       } while(len > 0);
58    }
59    return sb.toString();
60 }
```

Comment: It seems to be some kind of trick to treat tens of thousands different from hundreds of thousands and thousands. It seems to me that this algorithms is terribly complex for a not so difficult job, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing digit words into digits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924974/replacing-digit-words-into-digits)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about this code segment:

```
if (len > 3 && len % 2 == 0) {
   len++;
}
```

It means if len is larger than 3 (obviously!) and if len is an [even](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_number) number.

The `%` symbol is used for the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Modulo_operation_expression).

Wikipedia's definition about modulo operation is:

> In computing, the modulo operation finds the remainder after division
>   of one number by another (sometimes called modulus).

**Update**

Regarding the logic behind this code segment. I will only try to guess the original author's intentions. The `len` variable will hold the length of the number.

In case the length is less than 100 then the author will create the required string in the `} else { // Number is less than 1000` block. If you see better this code segment the `len` variable is never used except in the end where he makes it equals to zero to exit the loop.

So, for numbers < 999 the `len` is never used.

Now, for numbers > 1000 it is used and I guess the author needed to change it in order to use it for the array access. This is why the lines 23 to 25 are used for. So, for numbers 1000 to 9999 `len` is 4, for 10000 to 99999 `len` is 5 and for 100000 to 999999 `len` is 6. I guess without changing it the author couldn't access the required array values. That's my guess about why this code is used for.

However, I guess from the given strings that the method should work ok for numbers from 0 to 999999. Try this out thought:

```
int err = 0;
for(int i = 0;i<999999;i++) {
        try {
             numtostring(i);
        } catch (Exception e){                
            err++;
        }            
    }
System.out.println(err+" ERORRS");
```

This will print `900000 ERRORS`. It is for the case of 1000 and for all numbers from 100000 to 999999. These two cases aren't handled properly from this code. I find this whole `len` manipulation very buggy and hard to follow. I am not sure if the author had something else in mind.

Here is a revised version that it seems to work ok for numbers from 0 to 999999 and I find it much simpler to understand.

```
        public static String numtostring(int num) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // Count number of digits in num.
    int len = String.valueOf(num).length();

    String[] wordarr1 = {"", "One ", "Two ", "Three ", "Four ",
        "Five ", "Six ", "Seven ", "Eight ", "Nine "};
    String[] wordarr11 = {"", "Eleven ", "Twelve ", "Thirteen ",
        "Fourteen ", "Fifteen ", "Sixteen ",
        "Seventeen ", "Eighteen ", "Nineteen "};
    String[] wordarr10 = {"", "Ten ", "Twenty ", "Thirty ", "Forty ",
        "Fifty ", "Sixty ", "Seventy ", "Eighty ",
        "Ninety "};
    int tmp;
    if (num == 0) {
        sb.append("Zero");
    } else if (num >= 1000000) {
        System.err.println("Numbers > 999999 are not supported!");
        System.exit(1);
    } else {
        do {
            // Number greater than 999
            if (len > 3) {
                int n = num / 1000;
                sb.append(numtostring(n)).append("Thousand ");
                num = num % 1000;
                len -= String.valueOf(n).length();
            } else { // Number is less than 1000
                tmp = num / 100;
                if (tmp != 0) {
                    sb.append(wordarr1[tmp]);
                    sb.append("Hundred ");
                }
                tmp = num % 100;
                if (tmp / 10 == 1 && tmp % 10 != 0) {
                    sb.append(wordarr11[tmp % 10]);
                } else {
                    sb.append(wordarr10[tmp / 10]);
                    sb.append(wordarr1[tmp % 10]);
                }
                len = 0;
            }
        } while (len > 0);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

You could also eliminate the `do-while` loop by calling again the `numtostring()` with `n` as argument and appending it to `sb`.

Anyway, test it yourself before using it to make sure I haven't forgotten anything :) I hope I helped you a little!

**Update 2**

OK, so the original method as we discussed works ok for a number with length < 3. It works ok for a number of 4 and 5 digits but not for one of 6 digits.

Let's see how `len` is used:

```
   if (len > 3 && len % 2 == 0) {
      // if len is 4 it becomes 5, if it is 5 it stays as is
      // if len is 6 it becomes 7 and an exception occurs
      len++;
   }
   ...
   if (len > 3) {
         // puts the thousand part in tmp
         // so if num is 9000, len is 5 and tmp is 9 (9000/10^3)
         // if num is 99000, len is 5 and tmp is 99 (99000/10^3)
         // and if num is 999000, len is 7 and tmp is 9 instead of 999 (999000/10^5)
         tmp = (num / (int)Math.pow((double)10,(double)len-2));
         // If tmp is 2 digit number and not a multiple of 10
         // So, if tmp is 11 to 19 (num was 11000 to 19999) it enters the if
         if (tmp / 10 == 1 && tmp%10 != 0) {
            // if tmp is 11 tmp % 10 is 1 and the wordarr11[1] is eleven etc.
            sb.append(wordarr11[tmp % 10]) ;
         } else {
            // if tmp is not 11 to 19 it enters here
            // this means if tmp is 1 to 9 for num 1000 to 9999
            // if tmp is 10 for num 10000 to 10999
            // if tmp is 20 to 99 for num 20000 to 99999
            // if tmp is 100 to 999 for num 100000 to 999999

            // wordarr10 contains the dozens
            // if tmp is 10 this will be ten, if it is 20 this will be twenty etc.
            // if tmp is 1 to 9 tmp / 10 will return 0 and sb will append an empty string (wordarr10[0])
            sb.append(wordarr10[tmp / 10]);

            // wordarr1 contains the units
            // if tmp is 1 to 9 then tmp % 10 will return the tmp as it is
            // if tmp is 10 or 20 tmp % 10 will return 0 and append the empty string
            // if tmp is 23 tmp % 10 will return 3 and append the word three
            sb.append(wordarr1[tmp % 10]);
         }
         // if tmp is a positive numbers... we know it is but ok...
         // we append the word hundrend if len is 2 or three, which is impossible because we are in the if(len > 3) branch
         // if original len was 4 it have become 5 earlier so
         // if len is 5 the len / 2 is 2 and we append the word thousand
         // if len is 7 len / 2 is 3 and an out of bounds exception gets thrown
         if (tmp > 0) {
            sb.append(wordarr100[len / 2]);
         }
         // finally we remove the part of num that we have printed in order to print the rest
         // so if num is 1123 then it will become 123
         // or if it is 12123 it will become again 123 (because len is 5)
         // if len is 7 this will fail and for example 123123 will become 23123
         num = num % (int)(Math.pow((double)10,(double)len-2));
         // if len is 5 then we make it three in order to run the else branch and print the rest part
         // if len was 7 this would make it 5 and the same branch would run again which I guess is also wrong
         len = len-2;
```

The whole mess is created more or less from these two lines:

```
tmp = (num / (int)Math.pow((double)10,(double)len-2));
num = num % (int)(Math.pow((double)10,(double)len-2));
```

They should better use `1000` instead of `(int)Math.pow((double)10,(double)len-2)`. Then the rest would be like the else part more or less. See my first update where I do it like this in the revised code.

Finally,there is another problem. As I have said previously for 1000 there is once again an exception. This happens because the length counting is wrong.

```
int len = 1;
while (Math.pow((double)10, (double)len ) < num) {
   len++;
}
```

For 1000 it will return `len = 3` but for 1001 it will return `len = 4`. For 10000 it will return `len = 4` but for 10001 it will return `len = 5`.

If you have a specific question please ask :)

Comment: I would guess, that instead of (or in addition to) describing the java language, the question is about why would one increment `len` in such circumstances

Comment: Ah... you may be right :) I will have another look at the code and try to provide an answer to that also :)

Comment: @Master_ex, I think Deltharis is asking what I am asking for. :)

Comment: @Master_ex, what is the purpose of this statement, "len -= String.valueOf(n).length();"?

Comment: @LinMa See Update2 for the original code. The `len -= String.valueOf(n).length();` is used to get the length of n so the else branch will executed in the second iteration of the do-while loop. Now, the truth is that len will always be 3 in `len -= String.valueOf(n).length();` but I wrote it like this to be similar to the original code.

Comment: @Master_ex, thanks a lot, love the detailed insights, my confusion is in your code "len -= String.valueOf(n).length()" is called when len > 3 (mean numbers > 999), but why you minus the total length, other than just the sub-part which is above 999? I think your "if (len > 3)" branch only handles sub-part of the number > 999? Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @LinMa Beware, the original number is `num`.Then `n = num / 1000;` .So, for `num = 123456`, `n = 123`.The original len is 6 but after `"len -= String.valueOf(n).length()` it is 3.So, in the first iteration len is 6 and the `if (len > 3)` branch will be executed.The string `one Hundred twenty three` will be appended to `sb`.The `len` will become 3 and then in the second iteration the `else` branch will be executed.The string `four Hundred fifty six` will be appended to `sb`. `len` will become `0` and there will be no other iteration because `while (len > 0)` will be false.

Comment: @Master_ex, good catch! For your code, "(tmp / 10 == 1 && tmp % 10 != 0)", do you think it is good to write code in another way, 10 < tmp < 20? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa I kept the `else` branch as it was previously in my revised version. I think yes, it is more clear if you write it as `(tmp > 10 && tmp < 20)`.

Comment: @Master_ex, thanks for the confirmation, how the else branch is related to my question? I am asking whether "(tmp / 10 == 1 && tmp % 10 != 0)" could be written as (tmp > 10 && tmp < 20). :)

Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @LinMa I was just stating that I haven't changed this part of the code in the version that I have posted in the 1st Update :)

Comment: @Master_ex, thanks and I like your implementation better than original version I posted. Mark as answered.